# Error while calculating java Date difference

Tags: java, calendar, java.util.date

Calculating the difference between two dates (`java.util.Date`) in terms of no. of days look like very simple and we can find different ways to do that. I used the following code to calculate the date difference:

```
  public static long daysBetween(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
        Calendar date = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
        long daysBetween = 0;
        while (date.before(endDate)) {
            date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            daysBetween++;
        }
        return daysBetween;
    }
```

In `main()`, I used the following two dates :

```
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.set(2011, 1, 1);
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.set(2011, 1, 31);

    long difference = daysBetween(c1, c2); //
```

But the value of the variable `difference` is not consistent. It is sometimes 30 and sometimes 31. So, why that might have happened.

Is there any solution to use the method results a consistent output ?

Comment: I run several times i get only 30 not 31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the *date* part of the calendars, but not the *time* part.

Sometimes the clock will tick between the calls to `getInstance()` and sometimes it won't, hence the inconsistency.

Options:

- Set the time as well as the date, e.g. to midnight
- Use a better date/time library - [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - which has a more suitable representation (`LocalDate`). An important moral here is that if you can find a type which represents the exact information you have, and nothing else, that's likely to be a good fit and cause fewer complications.

Using `LocalDate`, you wouldn't even have to do the loop as Joda Time has good support for computing the differences between two values anyway.

```
LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(2011, 1, 1);
LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate(2011, 1, 31);
Days period = Days.daysBetween(days1, days2);
int days = period.getDays();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only setting the year, month and day.  The hours, minutes, seconds and milli-seconds are the current time (and thus different every time you run it)

I suggest you use Joda Time's LocalDate instead as it appears to does exactly what you want.